# How to get model attribute from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller

I'm using xcode 6 and had created model from my application. My model has title attribute on it and have session info to stored the list of models attribute. I have TableViewController that each time in this case will create a new model and add it to the session info. Each time the table try to load, the session info will get NSMutableArray of models. However, I can retrieve the NSMutableArray of the models, but not each of the model's attribute.

**viewDidLoad**

```
Model *item = [[Model alloc]init];
item.itemTitle = @"Item 1";
[[SessionInfo getSharedInstance] addItemBarCode:item];
```

**TableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[SessionInfo getSharedInstance] getItems];
cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[SessionInfo getSharedInstance] getItems];
Model *item = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = item.itemTitle;
return cell;
```